# SQL Server Mapping rooms from a site to another within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping

```
DECLARE @origSiteID int = 836,
        @newSiteID int = 838

INSERT INTO Rooms (Name, SiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive)
SELECT 
        Name, SiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive
FROM Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @origSiteID
```

The code above would do the following:

```
ID  Name    SiteID  ControlsSiteNum ControlsRoomNum IsActive
2025    E Terminal  838 63900   63901   1
2026    ARPT Kitchen    838 63900   63902   1
2027    ARPT Mgr    838 63900   63903   1
2028    W Terminal  838 63900   63904   1
```

Which is inserting all the rooms from the `origSiteID` into the `Rooms` table. Now, I want those 4 rooms which are inserted to be mapped to the `@newSiteID`!! would an update statement do the job? How would I map rooms from any `origsiteID` to any `newSiteID`?

This question was answered but I want to take it to a further step:
I want to take this into a further step. I want to produce a map that contains the original room ID and its new room ID equivalent for every room created. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `@newSiteID` in the `SELECT`

```
DECLARE @origSiteID int = 836,
    @newSiteID int = 838

INSERT INTO Rooms (Name, SiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive)
SELECT 
        Name, @newSiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive
FROM Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @origSiteID
```

**Appended after comment**
change the structure of your table:

```
ALTER TABLE Rooms ADD OriginalSiteID INT
```

Then the INSERT will look like:

```
DECLARE @origSiteID int = 836,
    @newSiteID int = 838

INSERT INTO Rooms (Name, SiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive, OriginalSiteID)
SELECT 
        Name, @newSiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive, @origSiteID
FROM Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @origSiteID
```

Comment: Hi Luis, I want to take this into a further step. I want to produce a map that contains the original room ID and its new room ID equivalent for every room created.  Thank you.

Comment: @HotlansyHttlandy , please see my edited answer. If you need further assitance, I suggest you opening a new  question; Since I'm finishing my day.

Comment: I opened a new question, thank you for your help but I really cannot change the table structure.